# Debris or Remains

Tags: word-choice

Please suggest the most proper word to describe the picture below.

[image]

Can I use "debris" to describe it?

Are they completely interchangeable?

Comment: *Debris* is usually used when one is discussing things that must be cleaned up.  I'd use *wreckage* or *remains* if I were discussing it from the point of view of analysis for example.  *Debris* gives no hint as to its origin while *wreckage* and *remains* allude to some prior form.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Debris* is broken-apart pieces of stuff arising from some sort of violent event that pulls things apart. (*Rubble* is a close synonym, although it carries more of a static feeling; we wouldn't usually say "rubble flying in the air," for example.) *Wreckage* is what's left of something identifiable that has been damaged beyond repair. *Remains* is also used in this context, but it is also used to refer to what's left of someone or something that has died, or a corpse. (We would not use *wreckage* to refer to such.)

A few pictures of tornado damage should clarify the differences.

This is a picture of flying debris from a tornado:

[image]

Here is a picture of a large piece of debris sticking through the wreckage of a car:

[image]

Here is the wreckage of a house and a truck after a tornado blew the truck into the house.  As you can see, there is a fair amount of debris scattered about:

[image]
<sub>(source: [dailymail.co.uk](https://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2012/04/04/article-2124648-1274D8CC000005DC-341_470x295.jpg))</sub>

And here are the remains of a neighborhood after a huge tornado demolished it.  As you can see, there is nothing left of it but piles of debris (or rubble) where houses used to be:

[image]
<sub>(source: [wxug.com](https://icons.wxug.com/hurricane/2013/moore_wide_destruction.jpg))</sub>

Comment: _"Wreckage ... would_ not _be used to refer to living things that have died ... wreckage and remains can refer to the same thing_

Comment: I wouldn't describe them in that way, since it seems like a two-way equivalency.

Comment: What improvement do you suggest?

Comment: "Remains" can refer to "wreckage". "Wreckage" can sometimes refer to "remains".

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't see what you're getting at.  My statement seems to me to amount to the same thing (if something is wreckage, it is also remains, but there are remains that are not wreckage) with some further elaboration.  Can you explain why you see yours as an improvement?

Answer (score 4):

For the item in this photo (an airplane) I would call this **wreckage**. This generally applies to things that are destroyed by some force, such as means of transportation (cars, trains, etc.)

*debris* in a very general sense could be used.

*remains* (as I use it) usually refers to living things that aren't living anymore, though by definition that is not the only usage.

Comment: I [disagree](http://www.google.com/#q=%22The+remains+of+the+building%22) with the assertion that _remains_ "usually" refers to living things. (It _can_, of course, but I wouldn't classify references to [aircraft](http://www.google.com/#q=%22remains+of+the+aircraft%22), [shipwrecks](http://www.google.com/#q=%22remains+of+the+ship%22), or [spacecraft](http://www.google.com/#q=%22remains+of+the+shuttle%22&start=10) as "unusual" or "rare".)

Comment: Fair enough. I updated my answer to indicate its the common usage I am aware of.

Answer (score 3):

*debris* or *remains* would be acceptable:

- The debris from the crash of Flight XYZ
- The remains of the aeroplane

However, *debris* and *remains* aren't completely interchangeable.

You would *not* use *debris* to describe parts of deceased/maimed living being.

- The remains of the man were discovered...
- **not** The debris of the man was discovered...

Also, I'd consider uses of *remains* as implying that the some kind of destruction or damage, whereas remains usually means more natural processes - what's just "left".

Answer (score 0):

Debris is broken-apart pieces of stuff left over after some sort of violent event that pulls things apart. (Rubble is a close synonym.) Wreckage is what's left of something identifiable that has been damaged beyond repair, but as jimsug has mentioned, it would not be used to refer to living things that have died. In that case we would always use remains. Remains are what is left after something or someone has been wrecked or killed. So often wreckage and remains can refer to the same thing.

Comment: This looks familiar.  :)

Answer (score 0):

**Wreckage** refers to one or more large pieces of something that has been *wrecked*, severely damaged by something other than time.
(e.g. the wreckage of a bus that has fallen over a small cliff).

**Debris** is from the French word *débris*, originally meaning to *break down*, and refers to many small pieces of wreckage or remains.
(e.g. the debris from a bus that had contained a terrorist bomb.)

**Remains** are what *remain* of something that has decayed, rotted, rusted, scavenged, etc. over a long time period (e.g. the remains of an abandoned bus).